# Sending email from a .net application via a mail server with a self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, smtp, self-signed

I installed hmailserver 5.3.2 and configured it. It receives and sends
emails normally, but I wanted to use it to send emails from a .net/C#
application located in another server, and for that I wanted to use
SSL communication. Before, the application was configured to send
emails via gmail, on port 587 and it worked ok, but now we want to use
our own mail server. We first configured the application to connect on
smtp.domain.com on port 25 and that works, it sends the email.

Then we
created a self signed certificate to test the if we could send the
message through a secure channel.I created the certificate with
openSSL setting common name as: mail.domain.com, smtp.domain.com,
*.domain.com, domain.com. I opened port 587 on the firewall and
configured hmailserver to use a certificate for inbound connections on
that port.
None of the certificates I created worked (I tried one and then
created another one and so on), generating the following (generic) exception in the
application:

```
System.Exception: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699
```

Of course I also tried to connect via telnet: telnet smtp.domain.com
587, and I just got a blank screen. It is not a firewall issue since
when I disable the ssl on port 587 I can connect normally.
Looking at the log doesn't even show an attempt to connect when using
587 with SSL.

I already checked these questions: [Getting SmtpClient to work with a self signed SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153790/getting-smtpclient-to-work-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate) and [Using a self-signed certificate with .NET’s HttpWebRequest/Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526711/using-a-self-signed-certificate-with-nets-httpwebrequest-response), but it didn't solve my problem. The approach with [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) didn't have any influence.

I tried with ports 25 (which is also proposed in one of the questions above), 465, 587, and with all 3 it happens the same: The initial handshake (SYN / SYN-ACK / ACK) and after about 80s the connection is closed (FIN), nothing in between.

Do I have to install that certificate somewhere so the .net application sees it as trusted? I mean, I already installed it as a Trusted Root Certification Authority and could check by running mmc, so I have no idea where to go now...

Thanks for the help!

PS: Not sure if this belongs to ServerFault since it concerns a C# application but also a mail server...

EDIT: Code sample:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com");
mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@domain.com", "pwd");
mailClient.Port = 587;
mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("mailAddressFrom", "mailAddressTo", "subject", "body");
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

EDIT 2: Log (Based on Ramunas' suggestion):

```
"TCPIP" 3588    "2010-06-23 10:02:49.685"   "TCPConnection - Posting AcceptEx on 0.0.0.0:465"
"DEBUG" 3588    "2010-06-23 10:02:49.809"   "Creating session 24039"
"TCPIP" 772 "2010-06-23 10:04:29.639"   "TCPConnection - SSL handshake with client failed. Error code: 2, Message: End of file, Remote IP: X"
"DEBUG" 772 "2010-06-23 10:04:29.639"   "Ending session 24039"
```

Comment: You might try providing a code sample of what you are trying to do.   I was going to post an answer, but it's the same as the some response on the self `signed link` above.

Answer (score 1):

currently, you can **not** send mail using c# 4/.NET 4 to a hMailServer regardless whether the certificate used by hMailServer is purchased or self-signed.

the problem is two part AFAIK ... c# 4/.NET 4 will only send using TLS and port 587; hMailServer does not currently support STARTTLS.  c# 4/.NET 4 does not support the alternative of 465/SSL.

see this thread ["configuring SSL confusion ..."](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21650) at hMailServer's forum.

["SmtpClient.EnableSsl Property "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx):
"An alternate connection method is where an SSL session is established up front before any protocol commands are sent. This connection method is sometimes called SMTP/SSL, SMTP over SSL, or SMTPS and by default uses port 465. This alternate connection method using SSL is not currently supported." -- MSDN

Answer (score 1):

As gerryLowry said:

> c# 4/.NET 4 will only send using TLS and port 587;
>   hMailServer does not currently support STARTTLS

You can update your hMailServer to hMailServer 5.5.1 (BETA) [here](https://hmailserver.com/download)
It now supports STARTTLS and with port 587 all is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sophisticated mechanism but in simple words client (computer you're making connection from) should know about WHO is certificate issuer (in your case your server is certificate issuer). If it does not find it in it's Trusted Root Certificate Authorities list then it considers this connection to be unsafe. (I bet you've seen browser warning you about unsafe request to some https://.... site).

Open Certificates snap-in in your Microsoft management console on a client computer and try to add the same self signed certificate to a Trusted Root Certificate Authorities list.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried this approach as you can see in the paragraph above the 'thanks' ....

Answer (score 0):

I installed hMailServer, created self signed certificate, added it to hMailServer and was not able to send mail via it, too. Though I was successful while sending emails without certificate.

I enabled logging on hMailServer (for everything) and tried again with no luck. But I saw an error in a log file stating

> "Severity: 2 (High), Code: HM5113,
>   Source: TCPServer::Run(), Description:
>   Failed to load certificate file. Path:
>   <...>test.cer,
>   Address: 0.0.0.0, Port: 25, Error: An
>   invalid argument was supplied"

Maybe this is a case on your hMailServer also?

Comment: Yeah, I should have enabled logging for everything already. Thanks for the push! I would give a +1 but I'm still short on reputation...
Anyway I updated the question with what the log shows, and it's a different error.

Answer (score 0):

I have port 25 as normal SMTP open on my hMailServer as well as port 465 for SSL, so I had to change my code to point to the normal SMTP configuration. It should work after that. As for SSL, sorry, it won't work on hMailServer...

```
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("me@myself.home", "Me");
        message.Body = "hello, World!";
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@myself.home", "You"));

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("secure.myself.home", 25);
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@myself.home", "pwd");

        client.Send(message);
```