# How can I trust an Active Directory Root CA Certificate in an Azure Web Application?

Tags: azure, ssl, https

I have an Azure Web Role with an SSL endpoint configured using a certificate obtained from my companies Active Directory Certificate Authority, and an Azure Web App that needs to connect to this Web Role over SSL.  As the Web App cannot verify the CA for the Web Roles SSL cert, the connection fails.

How can I trust my CA from within the Azure Web App?  If it were a full Windows Instance, the CA certificate would be added to the Trusted Certificate Authority store, so how do I do this with an Azure Web App?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot add a certificate to the trusted certificate authority on an Azure Web App. The security implications would be quite bad if that were possible.

However, what you can do is override the framework code for SSL verification to include your particular cert (for example in .NET this would be ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback). This stack overflow question and answer shows how to do that for .NET: [How to call the default certificate check when overriding ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058096/how-to-call-the-default-certificate-check-when-overriding-servicepointmanager-se)

Comment: Thanks, after spending a few hours on this, I decided it was more economical to purchase a certificate from a trusted provided.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but why would "The security implications would be quite bad if that were possible."?