# Add a new trusted CA to the Certificate Authority certificate store on Azure

Tags: azure, certificate, x509certificate

If you have a Website / Web-App on Windows Azure, then you can upload X.509 Certificates to the website's `Personal` certificate store for the purposes of allowing the client itself to use Client Certificates to authenticate itself when connecting to an external web-service.

However it doesn't seem you can upload your own Certification Authority root or intermediate certificates such that your Azure web-application can automatically validate the server certificates of external web-services that it itself connects to - at least there's no management GUI for this. Are there any Azure PowerShell commands for this, perhaps?

Is it possible to run .NET code that adds certificate binaries to the `StoreName.CertificateAuthority` (for `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`) store?

Comment: Did you ever found an answer?

Comment: @TomasDolezal No, unfortunately. I worked-around it by writing my own certificate validation function callback instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trust an Active Directory Root CA Certificate in an Azure Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884634/how-can-i-trust-an-active-directory-root-ca-certificate-in-an-azure-web-applicat)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, I think you are trying to deal this on the webapp level, and unable to see `root` or `intermediate` stores. I think it would be more clean to deal with this on the azure level.

Referring to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal/)

Certificates you upload directly to the cloud service will be available to your webapp/workroles. You should be able to upload root and intermediate cert to the cloud service and declare who is root/intermediate in your app follow the instruction in step 2.

Hope this can cover your usage.