# Installing certificates to the trusted root certificate store on azure web apps

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

How can I install a certificate into an Azure Web App so that my azure webapp can communicate with a remote service via SSL (this particular certificate is not signed by a public CA)

I generated an ssl certificate with openssl and when I install it to the trusted root certificate authentication store on my local computer the runs fine. However when I upload the cert via the management portal I get errors that the certificate isn't trusted (which is correct) and the correct error for when a certificate is not installed.

How can I install a private SSL certificate into the trusted root certificate store on an azure web app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unfortunately, we cannot add a certificate to the trusted certificate authority on an Azure Web App. The security implications would be quite bad if that were possible. More detail info please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884634/how-can-i-trust-an-active-directory-root-ca-certificate-in-an-azure-web-applicat).

But We can use Azure Cloud Service that allowed us to do that. More info please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal).

If we want to install certificates to **Personal certificate store** , we could upload a **.pfx**  file to the Azure App,  and add an App setting named **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application. Then the certificates will be installed to the **Personal certificate store** . More detail please refer to [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).
How to obtained an SSL certificate please refer to the official document [Secure your app's custom domain with HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate#what-you-need).

> The easiest way to get an SSL certificate that meets all the requirements is to [buy one in the Azure portal directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site). This article shows you how to do it manually and then bind it to your custom domain in App Service.

Comment: if i can't modify the trust ca store then how can I ever have a functioning certificate chain in an azure web app? Uploading an unsigned certificate to the personal store would result in a broken chain. Have I got something wrong here or are private certificates useless in azure web apps?

Comment: From the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate#what-you-need) `Get an SSL certificate- The certificate must meet all the following requirements:
It is signed by a trusted CA (no private CA servers). ...`

Comment: Hi thanks yes as you said you can't add a Trusted CA to a webapp which means you need a private certificate. Hopefully they will change this soon so I can sign it with my own private CA. I ended up just disabling SSL verification for the time being as a work around.