# Send email using smtpClient and smtpserver other than smtp.gmail.com

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I searched and came across many codes demonstrating mail sending using gmail's smtp with c#

Here is my smtpclient configured to send email.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = MailSettings.SMTP, // smtp server address here...
    Port = 465,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    Credentials = credentials,
    Timeout = 30000,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false
};
```

This code works very fine with host as smtp.gmail.com

But when it comes to other Hosts, it fails.

It doesnt send mails.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: It may be using other ports, not using SSL, etc. Did you check those things for the "other" SMTP host?

Comment: you need to check specific settings for other hosts e.g. port, host name, enablessl, credentials etc

Comment: It doesn't work isn't very specific. What is the error message?

Comment: It uses 465 post with SSL

Comment: @patrick Hofman. No error message. But mail is not received at the recepient

Comment: you need to understand that not all smtp servers use the same Port as well as SSL have you done a google search on System.Mail..?

Comment: If there is no error, is the service just slow?  Many services will retry several times over he course of a day before you get your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details about the error you are getting?
Several things can cause this:

- Server Configuration: are the ports correct? the server does not require authentication? the server supports ssl?
- SSL Certificate: the certificate is self-signed? If so you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153790/getting-smtpclient-to-work-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate);

Regards,