# Get the public key of a website's SSL certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm not really sure about whether the following is doable or not because I'm in no way an expert on the subject (security, certificates...etc).

Anyway, what I want to do is get the Public Key of a website's SSL certificate using C# code. Like is there a way to query that information from the site using an HTTP request or something?

In order for you guys to understand why I really want to do so, I'll briefly explain the scenario I want to make happen. Basically I have a bunch of websites that use OAuth 2.0 to achieve a state of trust among each other. So let's say `Site1` issued a request to `Site2` and sent it a token which is supposedly from a trusted Authorization Server. `Site2` should be able to verify the authenticity of this token.

I hope that was clear enough.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768670/does-httpwebrequest-automatically-take-care-of-certificate-validation . The answer to it shows how to perform custom validation and in the validation handler you can pick the certificate and extract its private key.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp thanks for the link, but this is not exactly what I need. What I really need is being able to query facebook.com to get its certificate information. The public key is all I need actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following block of code for a similar purpose. I hope it helps!!!

```
        Uri u = new Uri(url);
        ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(u);

        string groupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(u) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.ConnectionGroupName = groupName;

        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
        {

        }
        sp.CloseConnectionGroup(groupName);
        byte[] key = sp.Certificate.GetPublicKey();

        return key;
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I needed. I would appreciate it if you would comment your code snippet to highlight what the important bits are doing. Thank you so much anyway :)