# Is it possible to validate both self-signed and authentic certificates?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate

Say there is an application that needs to communicate with multiple servers, some of the servers are in development mode and are using a self-signed certificate.  Other servers are using an authentic certificate.

Is it possible to combine a technique like this which validates thumbprints of self-signed certs with the normal validation mechanism?

[Using a self-signed certificate with .NET's HttpWebRequest/Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526803/538763)

Saying it another way, I would like to chain a custom validation with the normal one when the custom one fails.  Does the default implementation occur when the following variable is non-null and the custom validator returns false?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

Edit:  Actually, looking at the signature of the validation callback it looks as if the callback is occurring *after* the regular validation?  Can anyone verify that is the case?

```
 bool ValidateServerCertficate(
        object sender,
        X509Certificate cert,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors); // are errors from the regular validation?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can call the default validator, but you don't have to. Implement the custom callback and look at the `SslPolicyErrors` enum. If it equals `SslPolicyErrors.None`, then it's a good certificate that would've validated anyway. Otherwise, do you custom validation.

```
internal static bool ValidateCerts(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        // Good certificate.
        return true;
    }
    //Do custom validation here
}
```