# Error while connecting to https webserice from windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am trying to access a ssl enabled webservice (*.asmx) from a windows 8.1 store app. the service call is throwing exception giving errors

> could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel.

and

> remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Application is working fine when the service host inside the windows 8.1 pro tab itself with http. But it throws error when connecting to service hosted on an outside network.

I am able to view the asmx in IE even though it shows certification error on the address bar. I tried to install the certificate from IE, even after installing, the error(red color) is still on the IE.

Any ideas on how to tackle this? Is there any thing I should take care of when consuming https service from Windows 8.1?

Comment: I'd fix certificate issues first... If you can't - see if you can disable certificate verification similarly to desktop version - similar to [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526711/using-a-self-signed-certificate-with-nets-httpwebrequest-response/526730#526730)

Comment: I have added the certificate to the Trusted Root. Still its not working.