# FTPS using fingerpring

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp, certificate

I have to communicate to an FTP server with SSL.

I've received an example on how to do that that uses, I believe, the WinScp command:

```
open ftpes://SomeUser:SomePass@SomeDomain.com/ -certificate="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
```

The question is how to use the `-certificate` part in an application? Do I have to save the string in a file or...?

For example if we use C#'s FtpWebRequest:

```
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(downlaodLocation);
```

how can we use this fingerprint?

X509Certificate class has a constructor that accepts byte[].

```
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx");
ftp.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(toBytes));
```

Is this the right way to use the certificate fingerprint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a self-signed certificate with .NET's HttpWebRequest/Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526711/using-a-self-signed-certificate-with-nets-httpwebrequest-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I took a different approach for uploading the file and used WinScp for c# lib for that.

```
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP.HOSTNAME"],
                UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP.USERNAME"],
                Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP.PASSWORD"],
            };
            if (port.HasValue)
            {
                sessionOptions.PortNumber = port.Value;
            }

                sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP.CERT.FINGERPRINT"].Trim();

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOG.PATH"]))
                {
                    session.SessionLogPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOG.PATH"];
                }
                session.Open(sessionOptions);
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions
                {
                    TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary
                };

                TransferOperationResult transferResult = session.PutFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FILE.TO.UPLOAD"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FILE.DESTINATION.NAME"], true, transferOptions);

                transferResult.Check();

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    result.Append(string.Format("Upload of {0} : {1}", transfer.FileName, transfer.Error));
                }
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: You have asked about SSL/TLS fingerprint for FTP (what can indeed by solved with WinSCP .NET assembly). But actually you have used SSH/SFTP in the end. What is a completely different protocol. Your answer should explain that.

Comment: Also your code `if (ShouldUseSSL()) sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = ...` makes little sense. First again, SSL and SSH are two completely different protocols. Second, you use SSH/SFTP unconditionally, so you also have to unconditionally set `SshHostKeyFingerprint`. There's hardly any scenario, where you can set `Protocol = Protocol.Sftp`, but not set `SshHostKeyFingerprint`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thnaks for the remarks, Martin. I've removed the `ShouldUseSSL` part. I've simplified the code for the SO answer, but forgot to remove the `if` there. My intent was to achieve the same result as the command from the question, so this is what has worked for me.

Comment: But, as I have explained already, the code in your answer does completely different thing (SFTP) than the code in your question (FTPS). SFTP and FTPS are two completely different and incompatible protocols.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've edited the answer to specify that this is a different approach.